# Using numbers converted into a string in a function

Tags: javascript, tostring

```js
 function getNumber(number){
  number = number.toString();
  if(((number[0]===2) && number[1]===4 || number[1]===6) && number.length===15){ 
    console.log("finally"); 
  } 
  else{
    console.log("this should work"); 
  }
}

getNumber(265674758686922);
```

Why doesn't this console log "Finally", and what can I do to make that happen in this function?

Comment: this is javascript right? please tag the question if so.

Comment: yes, however i see you beat me to the punch

Comment: After you've converted the number to a string with `.toString()`, it's no longer a number. `number[0]===2` etc can never be true because it's comparing a string to a number with strict `===` comparison. You'll have to do `number[0]==="2"` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison operands must be strings, and you must note left to right order of evaluation on the `&&` and `||` operators....

```
if( number[0]==="2" && (number[1]==="4" || number[1]==="6") && number.length===15)
                       ^                                  ^
                       |                                  |
```